# Telephoto and wide lens options missing from Camera app (iPhone 11 Pro Max)

Tags: iphone, camera

A couple of days ago I had the Camera app freeze + crash on my while taking a photo. After that, the options to select between the 3 different lenses (.5, 1x, 2) don't come up while in Photo or Video mode.

Also, while the options do appear in Time-Lapse or Slo-Mo modes, if I tap `2`, it goes back to `1x`.

When this started happening, I was on iOS 13.3.1. I tried rebooting the phone a few times, but I can't get the options back.

I now joined the 13.4 beta to see if maybe this was a software bug that was fixed, but sadly it wasn't. It still happens in 13.4 beta.

Is this a hardware problem? I have AppleCare+, but now with the whole lockdown thing it's hard or impossible to get a replacement..

Comment: What is the version of iOS installed on your iPhone? The current public version is iOS 13.4.1. You can try by updating your device to iOS 13.4.1 (It's a bug-fix release).

Comment: I meant I was in 13.4.1, and now I installed 13.4.5 beta. Same issue. I also just now erased all settings and set it up from scratch; same issue. I think it's a hardware problem. The telephoto camera is busted.

Comment: Sounds like a very reasonable explanation to me.